# Mysql join with not equal to having multiple rows

Tags: mysql

My two table are like

```
Table 1


uid     mail


1136    xxx@gmail.com
1231    xxx@ymail.com
```

And

```
Table 2

uid     rid

1136    3
1136    7
1231    5
1231    2
```

So I want to join these both tables and want to get the result uid where rid in table 2 is not equal to 3.

Please let me know if you doesn't understand my requirement.

Comment: So what's your expected output? and what have you tried?

Comment: SELECT mail FROM users LEFT JOIN users_roles ON (users.uid = users_roles.uid AND users_roles.rid <> '3'). But although uid 1136 is having rid 3 but it still came in result. I don't want that

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.uid, mail, rid
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.uid = t2.uid and t2.uid not in (select uid from table2 where rid = 3)
```

Comment: This is not correct as this query will also return 1136 which has rid 3. But I don't want that. I only want 1231 here as there is no rid 3 for that.

Comment: Yes i can see that let me check. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other solution than this although it's working but very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.uid, mail, group_concat(rid) as rids
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.uid = t2.uid
group by t1.uid
having not find_in_set(3,rids)
;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ea71/6)